# Different sum query from same table and join them

Tags: sql, join

I have two query from same table

```
SELECT userId,SUM(amount) AS totalDeposite FROM trx GROUP BY userId
```

Output:

userId  totalDeposite

---

```
 1   470
 2   30
```

query

```
SELECT userId,SUM(amount) AS totalFine FROM trx WHERE TYPE='fine' GROUP BY userId
```

output:

userId  totalFine

---

```
 1    20
 2    30
```

How can i get the result like

```
userId totalDeposite  totalFine
1       470           20
2       30            30
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try to use `case` as below

```
SELECT userId,
       SUM(case when TYPE='fine' then amount else 0 end) as totalFine, 
       SUM(amount) AS totalDeposite
FROM trx 
GROUP BY userId
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    select * from
    (SELECT userId,SUM(amount) AS totalDeposite FROM trx GROUP BY userId) as tD
    inner join
    (SELECT userId,SUM(amount) AS totalFine FROM trx WHERE TYPE='fine' GROUP BY userId) 
    tF on td.userId = tf.userId
```